# How to filter with two conditions while considering all the columns the same?

Tags: pandas

My input is this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc-01', 'fft-a', 'abc-02'],
                    'col2': ['xyz-1', 'pg-02', 'fft-b'],
                    'col3': ['pg-77', 'zzz-1', 'abc-03']})
print(df)

     col1   col2    col3
0  abc-01  xyz-1   pg-77
1   fft-a  pg-02   zzz-1
2  abc-02  fft-b  abc-03
```

I need to keep only the rows that contain at least one `abc` but at the same time don't contain any `pg`. It means we should end up with only the row index `2`.

For that, I made the code below but I can't understand why the index `0` isn't dropped.

```
final = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x:(x.str.contains('abc')) & (~x.str.contains('pg'))).any(axis=1)]
print(final)

     col1   col2    col3
0  abc-01  xyz-1   pg-77
2  abc-02  fft-b  abc-03
```

Can you guys tell me what's wrong with my logic ?

My expected output is this :

```
     col1   col2    col3
2  abc-02  fft-b  abc-03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

A possible solution, which fixes the logic of the OP's tried code (we need to use `all`, because *all* row elements must be `True`  concerning the absence of `pg`):

```
(df.loc[df.map(lambda x: ('abc' in x)).any(axis=1) & 
        df.map(lambda x: ('pg' not in x)).all(axis=1)])
```

---

**Explanation about the reason why the OP's code does not work**

The logic of the OP's code is that, for the first row, the first element will be `True` and, therefore, the respective `any` will also be `True`, which makes the first row to appear in the result -- `all` is indeed needed!

---

**Output**

```
     col1   col2    col3
2  abc-02  fft-b  abc-03
```